# Как обновить значение поля объекта массива?

Tags: c#, mongodb, update

### Структура данных

Есть такая структура данных в бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Поясняю структуру

1. Есть коллекция `Schools`
2. Она содержит в себе массив `Students`
3. Каждый элемент массива `Students` хранит в себе поле-массив `Lessons`
4. Уже массив `Lessons` хранит объекты, у которых есть поле **Id**

### Задача

Иногда, у объектов, хранящихся в массиве `Lessons`, нужно обновить значение поля **Content**. То есть **нужно обновить значение поля у объекта**, **но** никак **не объект целиком** или массив `Lessons`, который хранит в себе эти объекты.

**Код обновления должен выполняться на стороне сервера и быть на c#.**

### Вопрос

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: обновить значение в базе данных  через `Update MainDb.Schools set Content ='new content' where id ='your id'`  на сколько я понимаю клиент приложение запрашивает их от туда

Comment: @OXYGEN, извините, что забыл уточнить. Замена происходит на сервере через c#

Comment: Вопрос становится не понятным! 1) кто должен обновить контент ? клиент или сервер ? 2) если сервер то то должен  слать запрос в базу на обновление 3) если клиент то он должен слать серверу команду которую он выполнит или если у клиента есть доступ к базе , то обновить в базе

Comment: @OXYGEN, клиент отправляет серверу обновлённое значение поля **Content**. Сервер же должен обновить значение **Content** у объекта на новое значение, которое передал клиент. То есть сервер обновляет

Answer (score 0):

### значит это должно работать так

1. клиент отсылает контент и его ID которое надо обновить на сервер
2. сервер получив эти данные  обновляет  базу Update MainDb.Schools set Content ='new content' where id ='your id'
3. у клиента информация может обновится а)сразу если реализован функционал когда сервер отсылает команду клиенту о том что данные изменились и их надо загрузить заново б)после перезапуска приложения , или после того как клиент обратится к серверу и запросит актуальные данные

---

1. Вот посмотрите https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/
2. Вот Пример на C# https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-csharp-and-mongodb--update-operation

Comment: Может вы не заметили метку вопроса - я использую mongodb. А может я не знаю как написать такую команду в c#. Если это так напишите, пожалуйста, как это выглядит в c#

Comment: посмотрите сылку с mongodb не работал не скину вам надо было бы изменить вопрос :как обновить запись в mongoDB на c#

Comment: Спасибо за старания и ответ! А на счёт уточнения бд - думал что по метке посмотрят. Моё упущение

Comment: К сожалению я поспешил и не проверил информацию кодом. Данный метод не рабочий, так как он позволяет менять значение поля у вложенного объекта, только если он **не является** массивом. А мне нужно найти решение именно для массива.